# Creating a counter which resets itself every 30 seconds

Tags: python, python-3.x, counter

I want to create a function that counts till 30, but when it reaches 30 I want to reset it to starting point.

```
def countdown():
  global countDown
  countDown = int(time.time() - start_time)
  return countDown % 30
```

And then I want to print it like that.

```
print("You have " + str(30 - countdown()) + " time")
```

It works but when it reaches 0, it keeps counting below 0 like -1,-2 and it is not doing modula operation. So it doesn't reset itself. What can I do in this case ?

Desired case: 30 29.... 3 2 1 0 30 29 28
Recent case: 30 29 ... 2 1 0 -1 -2

Comment: When you say "not working" what do mean by that? Are you getting an error? Does it run but does not do what you expect?

Comment: It works but when it reaches 0, it keeps counting below 0 like -1,-2 and it is not doing modula operation. So it doesn't reset itself.

Comment: not able to reproduce with the added code `import time` and `start_time = time.time()`

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get it what you mean , I have two of them at the top of my code. @B.Go

Comment: countDown is not reset, but countdown() definitely works on my PC. move to %30 one line up if that's what you want

Comment: `def countdown():
    global countDown
    countDown = int(time.time() - start_time)%30
    return int(countDown) `

Still same case on my PC. @B.Go

Comment: @uqi8 ***"when it reaches 0, it keeps counting below 0 like -1,-2 "***: Catch *when it reaches 0* and set a new `start_time`

Comment: I reset start_time when it reaces 0, but still showing -1 -2 :(

Comment: You shouldn't reset, that's the point. You set `start_time` only once and it will start all over because of the modulo operation.

Comment: Yes you are right it should start again but it is not. Although I did not reset it, modula operation doesn't return positive and that's the problem.

Comment: "time as a floating point number expressed in seconds since the epoch, in UTC" so not even a problem around midnight. The only way to get a modulo < 0 is to have (time.time() - start_time) <0, hence start in the future. Something is really wrong in your code setting the start time!

Comment: Reading the various comments and answers, it seems this question is still unclear. Can you explain things a bit more?

Comment: I think I understand what they mean, I have attempted to create an answer that works with both their question and all of their comments. Hopefully it works, as if not it's going to have to be explained better.

Comment: Use `time.monotonic()` if you want to count the number of seconds elapsed. Only use `time.time()` when you want the actual time of the system clock, with all the messiness of daylight savings and leap seconds that entails.

Comment: @B.Go *"The only way to get a modulo < 0 is to have (time.time() - start_time) <0, hence start in the future."* `time.time()` is not guaranteed to be monotonically increasing. It can return a smaller number the 2nd time you call it, in real circumstances that don't involve time travel. From the docs: *"While this function normally returns non-decreasing values, it can return a lower value than a previous call if the system clock has been set back between the two calls."* https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I want to apologize from everyone for not explaining my question clearly because this is my first question. Secondly, as shown in example , I saw that I did not made any mistake about my code. First part is correct but when it prints `("You have " + str(5 - countdown()) + " time")`  showing me the negative ones because of I take the modula of 30 but showing it in print func " 5 - countdown()" . So when it becomes 15 it will return 15 but 5 - 15 = -10. Thanks for everyone who tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

The counter is not being reset using the modulo operator (`countDown % 30`). Try,

```
import time
def countdown(i):
  counter = i
  while True:
    if (counter == i):
      counter = 0
    print(counter)
    counter = counter + 1
    time.sleep(1)

countdown(30)
```

Comment: I cannot use time.sleep() func for it because I encountered many problems in my loops. I cannot interrupt the input operations.

Answer (score 0):

What I got from your code

```
import time
start_time = time.time()
def countdown():
  global countDown
  countDown = int(time.time() - start_time)
  return countDown % 30

print("You have " + str(30 - countdown()) + " time")
```

is working perfectly on https://www.python.org/shell/
Can't reproduce your problem. Or it's not with the code in your question!

Comment: I can't share all of my code and that's why I couldn't explain myself enough. I will give some inputs the code and when I do this, it will make some stuff and show me how much time left. We have 30 seconds and when it becomes 0, the second stuff will come and counter will begin the counting again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid using global variables. Also, use 4 space indentations.
I would use length of time as an input.

```
from time import time

def do_something():
    pass

def get_time(start_time):
    # returns how much time did it pass from event that started at start_time
    return time() - start_time

def countdown(countDown):
    start_time = time()
    # this is counter that attains consecutive values [0, 1, ..., countDown]
    current_count = 0
    while current_count < countDown:
        print(countDown - current_count, end=' ')
        while get_time(start_time) - current_count < 1:
            do_something()
            #warning: if do_something takes significant anount of
            #time forthcoming print won't be correct
        current_count += 1
    print(countDown - current_count, end=' ')
    return current_count

countdown(7)
countdown(5)
```

Also the purpose of

```
print("You have " + str(30 - countdown()) + " time")
```

is not clear to me. Use it wherever you want in your script.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the question being quite unclear, it is hard to create exactly what you're looking for. However, this code should work for you no matter how you intend it to be used.

**This code allows you to:**

- Make a timer
- Get the time left
- Run code while the timer is counting down
- Run code once the timer has ended.
- You can also reset the timer

**Code:**

```
import time

class countdown():
    def start(self):
        self.t = time.time()
    def remaining(self):
        return 30 - int(time.time()-self.t)


timer = countdown()
timer.start()
while True:
    print(30 - countdown(), "seconds remaining") #Still time left code
    if timer.remaining() <= 0:
        pass #30 seconds over code
        timer.reset() #Starts timer again
```

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, your function is not resetting your counter.
Try the following little modification:

```
def countdown():
  global countDown
  countDown = int(time.time() - start_time) % 30
  return countDown
```